# Why can't I solve this problem with coderbyte challenge #3?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

So the instruction to solve this problem is: "For this challenge you will be determining the largest word in a string."

and because I'm using JS, the instruction inside the challenge is:

> Using the JavaScript language, have the function LongestWord(sen) take the sen parameter being passed and return the largest word in the string. If there are two or more words that are the same length, return the first word from the string with that length. Ignore punctuation and assume sen will not be empty.

here is my code:

```
function LongestWord(sen){
    
    if (typeof sen !== "string") return "Argument not a string";
    var senSplit = sen.split(" "); //split up the string
   // console.log(senSplit);       //into an array of words
    
    for (var i in senSplit){ //strip out non-alphanumeric characters
        senSplit[i] = senSplit[i].replace(/\W/g, '');
     //   console.log(senSplit[i]);
    }
    
    var wordSplit = new Array();
    for (var j in senSplit){ //split up the strings into character arrays
        wordSplit[j] = senSplit[j].split("");
    //    console.log(wordSplit[j]);
    }
    
    var longest = 0;
    var longWord = "";
    for (var k in senSplit){ //compare length of character arrays
        if (wordSplit[k].length > longest){
            longest = wordSplit[k].length;
            longWord = wordSplit[k];
            
        }
    }
    sen = longWord.join("");
    return sen; //return longest word
}
console.log(LongestWord("Archer is the best cartoon on tv"));
//cartoon
```

But it just says "ERROR" and nothing more... Am I not following the instructions or what??

Comment: 1. your code does not run (missing a curly brace). 2. you should test your code on some input/output you define yourself. here you are just posting your code and saying debug that for me

Comment: Try `LongestWord("")`, for example. (I think you don't need to split and join the individual words; you can just juse the strings' `length`. If you wanto to split and join, the initial value of `longWord` should be an ampty array.)

Comment: @grodzi Actually I forgot to write it..I just edited my code.

Comment: @MOehm For some reason I kept running into an error when I checked for word lengths, I probably misspelled something(?) So I split the words up further, just to show the code who's boss.

Comment: Coderbyte just says Argument? Or it says that on another site? I modified the ending of the code to console.log from the original site which is a print statement - so people here could check it out quicker

Comment: you can get the length on a string, no need to split the string to make an array

Comment: I think you may have some problems with your"strip out non alphanum" (what is the definition of a word ? do they specify it must be alphanum only? what about accents or utf8 chars (like ㄲ) ?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing the error without knowing the input used, but you can shorten your algorithm by eliminating the loop that splits each word into an array of characters. You can get the length of each string directly.

```
function LongestWord(sen) {
    
    if (typeof sen !== "string") return "Argument not a string";
    var senSplit = sen.split(" "); //split up the string
    // console.log(senSplit);       //into an array of words
    
    for (var i in senSplit){ //strip out non-alphanumeric characters
        senSplit[i] = senSplit[i].replace(/\W/g, '');
        console.log(senSplit[i]);
    }
    
    var longest = 0;
    var longWord = "";
    for (var k in senSplit){ //compare length of character arrays
        if (senSplit[k].length > longest){
            longest = senSplit[k].length;
            longWord = senSplit[k];
        }
    }
    
    return longWord; // return longest word
}

console.log(LongestWord("Archer is the best cartoon on tv."));
```

This implementation of `LongestWord` also returns the longest word directly, instead of assigning it back to the input parameter `sen`.